# Select specific words from string which is not enclosed in double quotes

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string something like this:

**As, we know that development of "the" nation depends on people as well as government of the country.**

I need a regex to detect specific word say 'the' not enclosed in double quotes. After some random tries I found this ((\.?)(the)). This detects word 'the' enclosed in double quotes as well as which is not in between quotes. But I only want word 'the' without quotes in the string above. I really can't come up with it even after trying so many tries.

What I want is replacing all `the` that are outside double quotes and repalce them with 'THE' but don't want any change in double quotes. So if, user writes say, `the`, `tHE`, `ThE` or any combination) found outside of quotes just wanted it to convert into `THE`.

Comment: This is very easy: match what you do not want (ie `"[^"]*"`) and match and capture what you need `(the)` => `new Regex(@"""[^""]*""|(the)")`, and the `Groups[1]` will contain all the necessary data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the help. But, can you please explain how I can separate two groups as the regex selects the text which is outside and inside of double quotes.

Comment: What is the expected  result? Are you extracting, or replacing? Is this used inside C#/VB.NET code? If yes, please update your question with that information. Add details how you are using the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what I want is replacing all 'the' which are outside double quotes and repalce them with 'THE' but don't want any change in double quotes. So if, user writes say(the, tHE, ThE or any combination) found outside of quotes just wanted it to convert into 'THE'.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookarounds:

```
(?<!")the(?!")
```

Comment: This will also match `the` in `leather`

Comment: @Toto So does OP's pattern. If that's undesirable, use boundaries: `(?<!")\bthe\b(?!")`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This answer is based on the presumption that the quotes in the input string are balanced, and there are no escaped quotes. For a more complex grammar, a parser should be written.

You may match non-overlapping quoted substrings that have no double quotes inside, and skip them, while handling all other `the` (outside double quoted substrings) by *capturing* them with a `(...)` *capture group*.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "As, we know that ThE development of \"the\" nation depends on people as well as The government of tHe country.";
        var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"""[^""]*""|(the)", 
            m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() : m.Groups[0].Value,
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);   // Set case insensitive mode
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/HyYFwD)

The `"[^"]*"|(the)` pattern  either  matches a simple quoted substring with `"[^"]*"` or matches and captures a `the` into Group 1.

The `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() : m.Groups[0].Value` checks if Group 1 matched: if it matched, we got a quoted substring, it will be inserted back into the resulting string, else, `the` will be turned uppercase.